# Im trying to get values from Inputs in REACTJS but the result gets empty

Tags: javascript, reactjs, authentication, logging, frontend

```
import React,{useState} from 'react'
const initialState = { nombre: "" ,apellidos: "" ,email: "" ,contrasena: "" ,repetirContrasena: "" };

enter code here

    const handleSubmit=(e)=>{
     e.preventDefault();

      console.log(formData);
};

    const handleChange = (e) =>{ 
setFormData({ ...formData,[e.target.name]: e.target.value});
};
return(
<form className={classes.form} onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                <Grid container spacing={2}>
                    {isSignup &&(
                            <>
                            <Input name="nombre" type="text" label="Nombre" handleChange={handleChange} autoFocus medio />
                            <Input name="apellidos" type="text" label="Apellidos" handleChange={handleChange}  medio />
                            </>
                        )} 
                <Input name="email" label="Email" handleChange={handleChange} type="email" />
                <Input name="contrasena" label="Contrasena" handleChange={handleChange} type={showPassword ? "text" : "password"} handleShowPassword={handleShowPassword} />
                { isSignup && <Input name="repetirContrasena" label="Repetir Contrasena" handleChange={handleChange} type="password" />}
                </Grid>
```

This is the result.

```
{nombre: "", apellidos: "", email: "", contrasena: "", repetirContrasena: "", …}
**"": "123"
```

apellidos: ""
contrasena: ""
email: ""
nombre: ""
repetirContrasena: ""
**proto**: Object**
[Error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yXqiv.png)

I tried using onChange={handleChange},onInput={handleChange} instead handleChange={handleChange} but the result gets completly empty.

Comment: you forgot to bind a ```value``` attribute to the inputs & you need to use the ```onChange``` attribute, example : ```<Input value={formData.nombre} onChange={handleChange} />```

Comment: Yes, I also tried adding value={formData.nombre} or value={initialState.nombre} and changing handleChange to onChange or onInput but I get the same result

Answer (score 0):

As @VersifiXion pointed out you can use `onChange` attribute and `value` attribute for `input` tag. Note, `useState` wont' immediately update your state and it is always good to use `prevState` while updating state and it can be something like below -

```
const handleChange = (event) =>{
   // setFormData({ ...formData,[event.target.name]: event.target.value});
    setFormData( (prevFormDataState) => {
        let myPrevSate = {...prevFormDataState};
        return {
            ...myPrevSate,
            [event.target.name]: event.target.value
        }
    })
};
```

And `input`tag element can be written something like this -

```
<Input
                name="email"
                label="Email"
                value={formData.email}
                onChange={handleChange} type="email" />
```

Also, please look into this useful comment added by [@pilchard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68153752/why-my-setstate-gives-me-undefined-react)

Answer (score 0):

I created a file called Input to set attributes to INPUTS so I used nombre={name} instead name={name}. Sry im novice

```
export const Input = ({name,handleChange,label,autoFocus,type,handleShowPassword,medio}) => {
return (
   <Grid item xs={12} sm={medio ? 6 : 12}>
       <TextField 
       name={name}
       onChange={handleChange}
       variant="outlined"
       required
       fullWidth
       label={label}
       autoFocus={autoFocus}
       type={type}
       InputProps={name === "contrasena" ? {
           endAdornment:(
               <InputAdornment position ="end">
                   <IconButton onClick={handleShowPassword}>
                    {type==="contrasena" ? <Visibility /> : <VisibilityOff />}
                   </IconButton>
               </InputAdornment>
           )
       }:null}
       />
   </Grid>
)
```

}
export default Input;